# redirect function in CodeIgniter 2 with PHPUnit and CIUnit

Tags: unit-testing, redirect, phpunit, codeigniter-2

I am using PHPUnit 3.5 and CIUnit with PHING 2.4 for unit testing my CodeIgniter controller functions

The problem is when the function i tested contains a redirect() function, the testcase will stop and will not continue the execution. There is also no available error log for this.

What could be the problem for this? Do i have to download/update PHPUnit specific library?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this would be because the `redirect()` fn **exits** after doing a redirect (which is what you should be doing when you do a redirect to stop further code execution while waiting on the browser redirect).

**/system/helpers/url_helper.php:**

```
/**
 * Header Redirect
 *
 * Header redirect in two flavors
 * For very fine grained control over headers, you could use the Output
 * Library's set_header() function.
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the URL
 * @param   string  the method: location or redirect
 * @return  string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('redirect'))
{
    function redirect($uri = '', $method = 'location', $http_response_code = 302)
    {
        if ( ! preg_match('#^https?://#i', $uri))
        {
            $uri = site_url($uri);
        }

        switch($method)
        {
            case 'refresh'  : header("Refresh:0;url=".$uri);
                break;
            default         : header("Location: ".$uri, TRUE, $http_response_code);
                break;
        }
        exit;  <===<<< here is the exit
    }
}
```

The only way 'around' this is to eliminate the `exit;` after the redirect call.

**Ref:** http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this too.  I needed to test that a certain function was redirecting. I ended up just asserting that the new redirecting url ended with a certain string:

```
#Calling the controller method    
$this->ci->register();
#output the headers
$out = $this->ci->ouput->get_headers();
#check that the uri ends with where it is redirecting
$this->assertStringEndsWith('/user', (string)$out[0][0]);
```

Keep in mind unit tests are only for a particular method.  If you need to test multiple redirects going to different controllers/methods using something like selenium, as well as unit tests for each individual method.

Comment: I haven't seen a better way to do this, so +1

Comment: The redirect assert can be done with a shorter markup, using the **assertRedirects** : `$this->assertRedirects($GLOBALS['OUT'], '/user')`